# How to get WKWebView to show in background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11

I am trying to get an animated gif to play in the background, and have some labels and buttons appear on top. This code runs and shows the animated gif, however it does not show the buttons or label text.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView! = nil
var webViewBG: WKWebView?

  @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var signUpButton: UIButton!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        self.webViewBG = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webViewBG

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "WebViewContent", ofType: "html")
        let htmlURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath!)
        let html = try? Data(contentsOf: htmlURL)

        var req = NSURLRequest(url:htmlURL)
        self.webViewBG!.load(req as URLRequest)
        webViewBG?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false;

        self.loginButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.loginButton.layer.borderWidth = 2

        self.signUpButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.signUpButton.layer.borderWidth = 2        
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe the view hierarchy is wrong in your storyboard file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this line overrides your view controller's view where the buttons are:

`self.view = self.webViewBG`

Try

```
self.view.addSubview(self.webViewBG)
```

You might also need to tweak the z position so that the webView is located 'behind' the buttons, like this:

```
self.webViewBG.layer.zPosition = 0.5
```

Higher zPosition means the view stands out more 'towards' the user